# After building Qt statically, I can't get to compile / link an application on Windows 7 (GNU allocator error)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, gcc

I'm trying to statically link my app against Qt. 
This is what I did:

1. downlaoded the Qt libs 4.8.1
2. donwloaded MinGW
3. configured Qt with:

   configure -release -platform win32-g++ -nomake examples -nomake demos -no-rtti 
   -no-qt3support -no-scripttools -no-openssl -no-opengl -no-webkit -no-phonon 
   -no-style-motif -no-style-cde -no-style-cleanlooks -no-style-plastique -no-sql-sqlite
4. run win32-make
5. setup my project in Qt Creator (from the SDK 4.8 also) to release
   and to use the static lib.

add CONFIGURE += static to the .pro file

And I get this error (apparently something is not liking something about my code using std::vector<> ?):

```
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory `C:/PhotoChop-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2010__Qt_SDK__Release'
g++ -c -Os -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -fno-exceptions -Wall -fno-rtti -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -DQT_NO_DYNAMIC_CAST -I"..\..\..\Qt\4.8.1\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\Qt\4.8.1\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\Qt\4.8.1\include" -I"..\..\..\Qt\4.8.1\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"..\PhotoChop" -I"." -I"..\..\..\Qt\4.8.1\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\mainwindow.o ..\PhotoChop\mainwindow.cpp
In file included from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/mingw32/bits/c++allocator.h:34:0,
                 from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:48,
                 from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/string:43,
                 from ..\..\..\Qt\4.8.1\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h:54,
                 from ..\..\..\Qt\4.8.1\include/QtCore/qstring.h:1,
                 from ..\..\..\Qt\4.8.1\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:48,
                 from ..\..\..\Qt\4.8.1\include/QtCore/qobject.h:1,
                 from ..\..\..\Qt\4.8.1\include/QtGui/../../src/gui/kernel/qwidget.h:46,
                 from ..\..\..\Qt\4.8.1\include/QtGui/qwidget.h:1,
                 from ..\..\..\Qt\4.8.1\include\QtGui/../../src/gui/widgets/qmainwindow.h:45,
                 from ..\..\..\Qt\4.8.1\include\QtGui/qmainwindow.h:1,
                 from ..\..\..\Qt\4.8.1\include\QtGui/QMainWindow:1,
                 from ..\PhotoChop\/mainwindow.h:4,
                 from ..\PhotoChop\mainwindow.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of '__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<const PCOperator::OperatorInfo* const>':
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:92:11:   instantiated from 'std::allocator<const PCOperator::OperatorInfo* const>'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:73:60:   instantiated from 'std::_Vector_base<const PCOperator::OperatorInfo* const, std::allocator<const PCOperator::OperatorInfo* const> >'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:180:11:   instantiated from 'std::vector<const PCOperator::OperatorInfo* const>'
..\PhotoChop\mainwindow.cpp:55:35:   instantiated from here
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:82:7: error: 'const _Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference) const [with _Tp = const PCOperator::OperatorInfo* const, __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_pointer = const PCOperator::OperatorInfo* const*, __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference = const PCOperator::OperatorInfo* const&]' cannot be overloaded
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:79:7: error: with '_Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference) const [with _Tp = const PCOperator::OperatorInfo* const, __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = const PCOperator::OperatorInfo* const*, __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference = const PCOperator::OperatorInfo* const&]'
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `C:/PhotoChop-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2010__Qt_SDK__Release'
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [release/mainwindow.o] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [release] Error 2
01:24:28: The process "C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project PhotoChop (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is surely some issue about const'ness originating from PhotoChop\mainwindow.cpp:55:35 somewhere. It'll be something about your use of "std::vector<const PCOperator::OperatorInfo* const>" or so. Show us the code, otherwise its virtually impossible to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there's some issue with the mingw compiler vs the msvc one as far as

`std::vector<const PCOperator::OperatorInfo* const>`

I re-configured qt with -platform win32-msvc2010 and nmake instead of mingw32-make and the thing compiles just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the "-static" option in your configure params ?